# Installing the app from Microsoft Store takes cached development app instead

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm developing a Windows Store Application. During development I've tested the app by installing the package via sideloading. The app is now published in Microsoft Store, but if I try to install it from the Store, the development package gets installed instead. How to prevent Microsoft Store from installing the development package and install the published one instead?

I have uninstalled the development app via the context menu in Start menu, but the same development app will still get installed when trying to install the published app from Microsoft Store.

The issue happens only on my own machine, other developers and customers get the published production build as expected.

I think the development build version number was bigger than the version number of the build that got published in the end. I wonder if the issue could be related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to uninstall the installed side-loaded application first before downloading your app from the Store. If you already have it installed, the Store install will fail and the side-loaded app will stay installed instead of the Store version.

Comment: Thanks. I did uninstall the side-loaded application, it doesn't help. Updated the question with that info.

Comment: Can you send the link to the app in Store? I will try on my PC

Comment: Thanks, but I know that it works fine on other developer's machines, they get the published production build as expected. Updated the question with this info too.

Comment: Very weird indeed... I think this warrants an official answer